# Get CATEGORY PARAMETER Values from Custom Fields in Attask Api C#

Tags: attask, workfront-api

How to get CATEGORY PARAMETER Values from Custom Fields in Attask Api C#
Suppose we have a project template. there is a custom field like xyz this custm field has drop down values. i want to get that drop down values. iam using

- First i found the category ID of that template by searching all custom fields

https://companyurl.com/attask/api-unsupported/ctgy/5433689e0000c5ef03c7d699c7317aa6?apiKey=apiKey&fields=categoryParameters:parameter

- And then pass to the CATEGORY PARAMETER for retrieving the value of drop down but it says bad request..

https://companyurl.com/attask/api-unsupported/ctgypa/search?apiKey=apiKey&categoryID=categoryID

Pleae Help how to retrieve the values of that drop down..

Answer (score 0):

To view custom parameters add `parameterValues:*` to your request fields and you should get back your custom values.

Comment: please share the example i cant get it. I appreciate your help

Comment: client is the attask api client `var users = client.Search(ObjCode.USER, new { isActive = true, fields = "emailAddr,ID,parameterValues:*" });`

Answer (score 0):

```
attask/api/v4.0/ctgy/search?apiKey=apiKey&ID=CategoryID&fields=ID,categoryParameters:parameter
```

It will give you parameters and their ids you have select your dropdown params ID and pass it to the query below.

```
attask/api/v4.0/PARAM/search?apiKey=APIKEY&ID=Your PARAMETER ID&fields=parameterOptions:value
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody struggles with this, the category ID is the ID for the Custom Form in which the Custom Field is used.

That means, if you want to lookup all custom forms you can use this query:

```
https://companyname.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/ctgy/search?fields=['*']
```

This returns you all Custom Forms in a list.
Then you can search for the description or something to identify the Custom Form your Custom Field is saved to.

Example:

```
{
        "ID": "5fe04ff00007e1216212c6ce92ca7de5",
        "name": "This is my personal custom form",
        "objCode": "CTGY",
        "catObjCode": "TASK",
        "customerID": "9d3c6e925ebbc77940007f01002441",
        "description": "These properties are needed at Task level for my Project",
        "enteredByID": "5e4e323455e8a9664444b876b377",
        "extRefID": null,
        "groupID": "57e3a25c000c62b6b3e1568e8e0d0090",
        "hasCalculatedFields": true,
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-12-22T14:30:18:191+0100",
        "lastUpdatedByID": "5e4e323455e8a9664444b876b377"
    }
```

The "ID" field is the